# How would I style this inline?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

How would I give #{self.o_cord.name} and #{self.o_product.full_name} an inline style making their background color orange? They are in an .rb file, I'm not sure if that changes anything. Thanks in advance!

```
if self.o_connection.dongle? 
  return "Plug the #{self.o_cord.name} end of the #{self.o_product.full_name} into the #{self.i_product.full_name}."
```

Comment: as in, what selectors and attributes to use?

Comment: Yeah, I'm unsure of the syntax of how to put inline CSS in the return statement

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the string out of your model and instead call the o_connection.dongle? from your view.  Then in your view, you can simply wrap the keywords in a span and style via css.

View:

```
<% if SomeClass.o_connection.dongle? %>
  <p>Plug the <span class="info-label"><%= self.o_cord.name %></span> end of the <span class="info-label"><%= self.o_product.full_name %></span class="info-label"> into the <span><%= self.i_product.full_name %></span>.</p>
```

CSS:

```
span.info-label {
  background-color: 'orange';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Haml Inline css Example:

```
= f.text_area :short_description, :style =>'background-color:'orange';'
```

erb

```
<%= f.text_field :short_description, :style => 'background-color:'orange';' %>
```